# Optimize imports on the fly for all projects in Android Studio/IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

**Is there a way to optimize imports on the fly for all projects, not just 'for current project' in Android Studio/IntelliJ?**

## Expected

Optimize imports to be enabled when opening an existing project and/or when creating new projects.

## Observed

`Add unambiguous imports on the fly` is IDE-level settings. However, `Optimize imports on the fly` does not appear to be as the parenthesis state `for current project`. I've tested this by creating a new project and opening the settings. As expected, `Add unambiguous imports on the fly` is selected while `Optimize imports on the fly` is not selected.

The current IntelliJ documentation, [Auto imports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html), does not provide a solution.

[image]

## Attempted solution

Enable `Optimize imports on the fly (for current project)` under *Preferences for New Projects...*

This produced the same observed result above.

[image]

[image]

This has also been added to the [IntelliJ community forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007960300-Optimize-imports-on-the-fly-for-all-projects-instead-of-for-current-project-).

Comment: How are you defining "all projects"?

Comment: The desired goal and what I mean by 'all projects' is for this to be a default setting moving forward when opening an existing project or creating a new project.

Comment: Then it would seem that checking that checkbox is what you want. You are looking at IDE-level settings, not project-specific ones.

Comment: `Add unambiguous imports on the fly` is IDE-level settings. However, `Optimize imports on the fly` does not appear to be as the parenthesis state `for current project`. I've tested this by creating a new project and opening the settings. As expected, `Add unambiguous imports on the fly` is selected while `Optimize imports on the fly` is not selected.

Comment: OK, that's a really strange settings UI design.

Comment: It is indeed, it would be nice to not have to enable each time a new project is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible until [IDEA-237002](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237002) is fixed.